# Можно ли улучшить код?

Tags: ассемблер, java, reverse-engineering

**UPD**: Прошу у общества прощения, первый вариант вопроса был с не тем куском кода. Copy-past error всегда будет жив! ;)

Собственно есть код:

```
private void optimizeDecByMemJnzb() {
    for (int curAddress = 0; curAddress < program.size(); curAddress++) {
        Instruction curInstr = program.getInstructionByAddress(curAddress);
        boolean isItDecByMemIndex = (curInstr.getOpcode() == Opcode.DEC_BYTE_MEM)
                && (curInstr.getReferencesCount() > 0);
        if (isItDecByMemIndex) {
            Instruction nextInstr = program.getInstructionByAddress(curAddress);
            int nextAddress = nextInstr.getJmpOffset() + 1;
            boolean canBeOptimized = (nextInstr.getOpcode() == Opcode.JNZB_OFFS)
                    && (nextAddress == curAddress);
            if (canBeOptimized) {
                nextInstr.markAsOptimized();
                curInstr.setOpcode(Opcode.MOVB_MEM_ZERO);
                curInstr.setReferencesCount(curInstr.getReferencesCount() - 1);
                curAddress++;
            }
        }
    }//for
}
```

Некоторые подробности, которые и знать-то вроде не надо. Привожу чтобы избежать лишних вопросов:

Целью этого кода является небольшая оптимизация некоторой программы для некоторого процессора. Ищет конструкции вида:

```
@@:
  dec byte[mem_index]
  jnzb @b // jmp if byte by mem_index is zero
```

и заменяет на новую:

```
  mov byte[mem_index], 0
```

**Nota bene:**
Это псевдо-ассемблер и не следует искать аналогии из мира Intel x86-64 архитектуры.

Comment: по внешнему виду выглядит уж очень усложненным. Вам нужно искать просто последовательность из двух команд заданного вида?

Comment: А опкоды нельзя сделать константами и не передавать каждый раз в метод?

Comment: Прошу простить. Не тот кусок кода вставил ((( Вопрос обновил, вставив тот самый кусок кода.